# How can I create a WCF behavior element extension without a separate assembly?

Tags: wcf

I have WCF web application project and I've added three classes to the App_Code folder. Now I want to register one of these classes (which inherits from BehaviorExtensionElement) as an Extension Configuration Element.

I'm in the WCF Configuration Editor and I'm at this screen:

[image]

When I browse for the Type, I'm forced to choose from a set of DLLs. But my Behavior Extension Element isn't in a DLL. It's in app_code.

So how do I choose it? Do I have to put it in a separate library?

**UPDATE:**
You can definitely do it within a WCF Class Library, which is where I was doing my testing for this particular feature. Then I implemented it in a WCF Web application and it didn't work. Alright. Well, I just created a library and included it and everything is working now. Still would like to know if anybody can get it working without a separate DLL.

Comment: It might be possible to do this without having the code in a separate library, but I highly doubt it.  I would suggest extracting the code into a separate class library and compiling the DLL, then adding the extension.